# Accessing getter and setter from other viewcontroller

Tags: swift, getter-setter

In my class A, i have a variable defined as follows:

```
var auth_token:String?
var _auth_token:String {get{return self.auth_token!} set{auth_token = newValue}
```

now i want to access this auth_token from other viewcontroller class. How can i achieve this. If i make a new instance of the class it will return me nil as expected.

Comment: Make your class A singleton! then access _auth_token property

Comment: What's the purpose of declaring two similar variables and why is `auth_token` optional when it is forced unwrapped anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your class A singleton using,

import Foundation

```
class A {
    static var sharedInstance = A()
    var myVariable : String! = nil

    private init () {
        //no need for any implementation
        //empty init removes all possibility of duplicate instance of class A
    }

}
```

As you can see there is a static variable named sharedInstance and a string variable called myVariable in class A.

Declaring sharedInstance as static and providing empty implementation of private init makes your Class A singleton.

Now whatever you set the value of myVariable no matter where all your VCs will get the same value :)

You can access it using,

```
let test = A.sharedInstance.myVariable
```

Hope it helps :) Have fun

Comment: Thanks. I used your approach and was able to solve the issue.